# Closing cmd.exe after command line runs

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Why I can't close the window DOS generate from this code using `cmd.exe` in batch file?

```
set "params=%*"
cd /d "%~dp0" && ( if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ) && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>nul 2>nul || (  echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~sdp0"" && %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"  && exit /B)

%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f && exit /B
```

Comment: `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /k` .. see the /k?  Make it /c

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas-ReinstateMonica I have changed `/k` for `/c`... the window not closed

Comment: Did you change both of the `/k`s?

Comment: DOS doesn't generate anything, you're not using a DOS, you're using a Windows. Your issue regardless of the question posed, is that you don't appear to have any idea what your provided code is written to do. I say that because my interpretation is that you you either do not understand how `&&` and `||` work, and/or don't know how to parenthesize your command blocks. In addition to that, you may not know that on some Operating Systems, _Windows 10 for instance_, a standard, (unelevated/non-admin), user can run fsutil.exe, so your code would treat them As administrator when they're not!

Answer (score 0):

said that what you are looking for is dangerous for the security of your operating system, this is the right code

I hope it's experiment...

```
set "params=%*"

cd /d "%~dp0" && ( if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ) && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>nul 2>nul || (  echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~sdp0"" && %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"  && exit /B)

start "" reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

TIMEOUT 3 && exit
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Now closes the window with your suggestion. Actually this is an exercise assigned by my computer teacher and i don't think he doesn't know what he writes...